# what is the best choice here

Tags: past-tense

> "I was about to email you why I have not received the parcel when..."

I was wondering if present perfect  for receive is a good choice since at the time of writing the parcel has not arrived or should I use past perfect to match tenses. I don't think so because the situation is still the same.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this works fine, though with a slight modification:

> "I was about to email you **as to** why I have not **yet** received the parcel when..."

The first addition is unrelated, but the focus for your question is to add a qualifier. Saying you have not *yet* received the package is a very concise way of saying:

> "At the time of writing, I have not yet received the parcel..."